# CSV file max column length?

Tags: java, csv

I write java code to download CSV file ,
I have 40GB sapce remains on drive
File size of CSV is only 30KB
**1) if headers size is less then file download no problem

3) if headers size reaches more than 700 then server stop automatically and  after file opening giving error as file column size exceed. 
It hide some column automatically**

**

> I read CSV column related question all answer says that no column
>   limit of csv file then Why i am getting this issue

**

Comment: This must not happen as CSV are simply flat files which basically don't have any restrictions. Share the code so that people can help you out.

Comment: Code snap cant share for security purpose, But I just take start date to end date from DB and write all these between dates are CSV header In StringBuilder and write it

Comment: When I debug code each line execute properly.

Comment: You getting problem in opening file? Simply open the file in notepad to verify or Try to open it with google spreadsheet. It mush not have any limitations.

Comment: Yes I checked it , I get different output on each system On windows it open , But on Centos 6.0 show error message and removes some header from CSV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CSV format has no column limit, but some applications that open or process CSV files may have limits.  For example, old versions of Excel could not handle more than 256 columns.